# How to fix empty space between a border and a background in button with rounded corners?

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, templates

I have created a simple button template for my WPF application:

```
<Style x:Key="DialogButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="buttonBorder" CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" MaxHeight="30" MinWidth="70" Margin="0,8,8,8">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource WindowBackColor}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But as you can see in the screenshot below, buttons have a small empty space in the corners:

[image]

Here is a zoomed in part of the button:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding another border for hover on top of the existing finally does the trick with desired effects:

```
<Style x:Key="DialogButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="buttonBorder" CornerRadius="8" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" MaxHeight="30" MinWidth="70" Margin="0,8,8,8">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Name="buttonHoverBorder" CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource WindowBackColor}" Visibility="Hidden" Background="Transparent" MaxHeight="30" MinWidth="70" Margin="0,8,8,8" 
                        Width="{Binding ElementName=buttonBorder, Path=Width}" Height="{Binding ElementName=buttonBorder, Path=Height}"> 
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="buttonHoverBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 19):

WPF renders the elements with anti-aliasing by default and this can result in small gaps between shapes.

Set the `EdgeMode` to `Aliased` on your `Border` this should get rid of the small gap

```
RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
```

Example:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Name="buttonBorder" CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" MaxHeight="30" MinWidth="70" Margin="0,8,8,8">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource WindowBackColor}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Result:

Before(anti-aliasing): [image: Before] After(aliased):[image: After]

---

### Option 2:

Another simple option is to change the `Grid` in the `Style` to a `Border` and set the `Background` and `CornerRadius` the same but set the `Margin` to -1, this will result in a smoother apperence than using `Aliased` and remove the small gap

Example:

```
<Border Name="buttonBorder" CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}" MaxHeight="30" MinWidth="70" Margin="0,8,8,8">
    <Border CornerRadius="8" Margin="-1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
</Border>
```

Comment: Using aliased rendering removes the gap but then the corners are not smooth enough and with  the rest of the controls smooth it really stands out. I think that I have found a trick to do this :) (take a look at my answer).

Comment: I also added a smoother example :), but yours also seems fine.

Comment: But I don't really like negative margins (it's just the way I work) so I will stick to my solution :)

Comment: Could it be a DPI setting? I'm experiencing the same issue, and I have 125% DPI set (Windows 8.1).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `BorderThickness` property of your `buttonBorder` `Border` to either `"0"` or a larger number. Having said that, I've never seen this before on any of my `Border` elements... are you *really* sure that isn't just some distortion on the *image* of the button?

Comment: I need to have some BorderThickness because of the mouse over trigger. Setting it to a larger number does not help, the empty parts are still there.

Comment: Yes I am sure that it is not a distortion on the image. As sa_ddam213 pointed out, it is caused by anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck on this for quite a while now, periodically having some issues with button styles. The answers above helped me a lot, but all of them have some flaws.

- Aliasing makes it blurry
- Border for hover requires change of margin for different border thicknesses

As i wanted to make my own style library for using in multiple projects, those were not great solutions, even though it could do the job for every style in particular.

Well, it seems very simple now, and tell me if i'm wrong, but an additional border in the root of the template does the job as expected.

Positioned below other elements, with no Thickness, it should have Template Background color as Background. Give it size properties from the inner border and enjoy!

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" MaxHeight="30" MinWidth="70" Margin="0,8,8,8">
                    <Border Name="buttonBorder" CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[link to the picture before/after, 4 kb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkQLP.png)

Note that you'll have to change the color of this border in Triggers if you are changing other colors by Triggers as well. Otherwise it would stay the same as in static state and will be visible in the gap when pressed/hovered.